DDD: How do I define my bounded contexts for a junction table shared by two aggregate roots?
I am puzzling over what seems to be a simple enough problem related to the boundaries of my Aggregates in a Domain-Driven Design project. I have prepared a SQL Server database called 'AuthDB' with four tables: 1. dbo.User; dbo.UserDetail; dbo.Role; and dbo.UserRole. dbo.User contains the user's ID, hashed password, and salt, while dbo.UserDetail contains the user's first and last names and phone number. dbo.Role contains Admin, User, and any custom roles (which can be added by users with Admin privileges). Finally, dbo.UserRole is a junction table with three fields, UserRoleID, UserID (foreign key referencing dbo.User), and RoleID (foreign key referencing dbo.Role). I also have defined CRUD operations such as dbo.spRegisterNewUser, dbo.spUpdateRoleName, etc.
I'm now trying to define my Aggregates, Aggregate Roots, and bounded contexts and am quite stumped as to how to handle dbo.UserRole.
On the one hand, User, UserDetail, and UserRole all seemingly fall within one Aggregate. One business requirement, reflected in the way I defined dbo.spRegisterNewUser (using a SQL Transaction), is that when a User is added, a UserDetail record also must be added simultaneously, and a UserRole record also must be added simultaneously (to ensure that a new User is not created with ambiguous or undefined admin privileges). As relevant here, any insertion to the dbo.User table necessarily must involve inserting a new record into dbo.UserRole.
On the other hand, if a request is made to delete a custom Role that was previously added--I won't allow deletion of Admin or User--we need to ensure that there are no orphaned records left in dbo.UserRole where a User has been associated with a now-deleted Role. For that reason, I use a SQL Transaction again within which all records in dbo.UserRole for which @RoleID = RoleID are deleted, and then the record in dbo.Role for which @RoleID = RoleID is also deleted. Any deletion from Role necessarily must involve deletion of records from UserRole. At the same time, though, the other CRUD operations of inserting a new Role or updating the RoleName for an existing Role do not implicate UserRole at all.
I know that the rule is to have one aggregate per repository. Obviously, I'll need a UserRepository. I'm admittedly less confident of needing a RoleRepository--I could conceivably say that there's no point in defining a Role without eventually identifying that Role with one or more Users, and therefore, Role can also be managed under the UserRepository rubric--which, I guess, would solve the contextual boundary problem. But it seems counterintuitive and frankly a little weird. I go to the UserRepository to make changes to the Role table, which does not implicate the User, UserDetail, or UserRole tables at all (aside from dbo.spDeleteRole), and, but for dbo.spDeleteRole, would be a completely standalone entity that is almost crying out to be an Aggregate Root itself. Or, I could create a separate RoleRepository for inserting, updating, and deleting Roles--but then that means that UserRole is changed by the RoleRepository, hence must belong to the Role Aggregate, not the User Aggregate, yet UserRole is also being changed by UserRepository via dbo.spRegisterNewUser.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to structure my Aggregates, Aggregate Roots, and bounded contexts here. More generally, what are best practices with drawing boundary lines for Aggregate contexts? How are junction tables and other "shared" resources typically (or more precisely, best) handled in an enterprise-grade development or production environment, say assuming a modular monolith architecture? Thanks in advance for all your thoughts...
In addition to considering the various ways I could draw the boundaries around the various tables to form my bounded contexts, I also considered raising a RoleDeletedDomainEvent. I think this could conceivably 'work' in the sense of compiling and producing valid states for my database at all times, but it's far from ideal. More specifically, only Aggregate Roots are supposed to raise Domain Events, so a first attempt might be to say that Role, an Aggregate Root, would publish RoleDeletedDomainEvent, and UserRepository could subscribe to the event and change dbo.UserRole, albeit eventually and asynchronously, by deleting the appropriate records from UserRole (which, in this approach, would belong to the User Aggregate). However, doing it that way would completely fail from a SQL perspective--the two must be effectuated as one simultaneous SQL Transaction or else my database will be left in an inconsistent state after deleting a Role that is still referenced in records in dbo.UserRole. So I'd be forced to do something like have Role raise a RoleMarkedForDeletionDomainEvent upon receiving a request to delete a Role, then have UserRepository handle that event by deleting the appropriate records from UserRole, and then have User raise something like UserRoleRecordsDeletedAsPartOfDeletingRoleDomainEvent, and then have RoleRepository subscribe to THAT event and use it as a trigger to delete the appropriate record from Role. I'm pretty sure this can be made to 'work', but it sure doesn't feel right.
